# Difference between includes..references..where and includes..where..references

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `Rails5.2` and read project code like

```
blog = Blog.includes(:posts).references(:posts).where(uuid: params[:uuid])
```

When I searched on the internet, I got examples like [link](http://blog.ifyouseewendy.com/blog/2015/11/11/preload-eager_load-includes-references-joins/)

```
Blog.includes(:posts).where(name: 'Blog 1').references(:posts)
```

Are there any differences for placing `where` clause before or after `references` clause?

Answer (score 1):

You should read `joins`, `includes`, `preload`, `eager_load` & `references` from [reference](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where)

Note: includes do not create separate query always.

`references` is used after `includes` & before `where` clause (I used while migrating project from rails-3 to rails-5 to resolve column ambiguity issue)

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34648805/10522579) also.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) here, you can see the definition of references.

In short terms, the `includes` will run a separate query to get all your `posts` (in your example) instead of getting them every time you loop through a blog.

Now for references, of you want to add a `where` condition on the `posts`, you'll need to add it. In your case, you don't need to include it.

Small example:

`blog = Blog.includes(:posts).where(uuid: params[:uuid])` -> will run a query to get the Blog from `blogs` and a query to get all the `posts` related to this blog.

In another case, like this: `blog = Blog.includes(:posts).references(:posts).where(posts: { name: 'test' })` you'll have to use the `references` or your `where` condition will throw an error

Comment: note `includes` do not create separate query always.

Comment: Hell! Help me please..how to get data from 3 connected tables
ProjectsSow.includes(:project).references(:project).includes(:member_allocation).references(:member_allocation).where(............)
?